# uWebsocket sending messages via WebSocket outside of the .message Behavior context

Tags: c++, types, c++17, uwebsockets

I have to open with the obligatory, I'm pretty trash at c++, fresh out of college.

I setup uWebsocket as a server, it's currently just echoing responses back to the client.

I am trying to setup a queue on a separate thread that can respond to the client at times OTHER than when I recieve a message.
I'm killing myself over here though because I cannot find the appropriate type for a function outside of the context of the main thread.

```
void RelaySocket(){
    struct SocketData{
        //Empty because we don't need any currently.
    };
    uWS::App()
    .listen(8766, [](auto *listen_socket){
        if(listen_socket){
            std::cout<< "Listening on port" << 8766<< std::endl;
        };
    })
    .ws<SocketData>("/*",uWS::TemplatedApp<false>::WebSocketBehavior<SocketData> {//I have to explicitly declare the type of this struct.
    .open = [](auto *ws){
        std::cout<< "test"<< std::endl;
    },
    .message = [](auto *ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode){
    
    //The docs show how to send messages from this context, but no other method is demonstrated.
    ws->send("My message");// This works fine enough. 

    //What I'm trying to do.
    outerFunction(ws);
    }

    }).run();
}

void outerFunction([Unknown Type] *ws){// I have NO idea what type would play nice in this spot. I've tried uWS::Websocket<false>, and others to no avail.
//Processes information before replying
...
//sends n amount of reply's.
ws->send("sick Data.");//the outcome I'm looking for. 
}
```

I've tried using the [Type_def](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/) feature, and it still isn't playing nice.

```
std::cout << typeid(ws).name() << std::endl;
```

returned

> PN3uWS9WebSocketILb0ELb1EZ11RelaySocketvE10SocketDataEE

My first post, so my bad if I didn't post all applicable information.

EDIT:

. the code below worked for me. Thanks again.

```
struct SocketData{
//Empty because we don't need any currently.
};
void SocketResponse(uWS::WebSocket<false,true,SocketData> *ws ){
ws->send("test");
std::cout<< "test"<<std::endl;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the uWebsocket docs, the type of `ws` is: `WebSocket<SSL, true, int> *`
Thus, you can try to use the following. Note: You probably need to forward-declare `outerFunction` as well.

```
void outerFunction(uWS::WebSocket<SSL, true, int> *ws);

void RelaySocket(){
    struct SocketData{
        //Empty because we don't need any currently.
    };
    uWS::App()
    .listen(8766, [](auto *listen_socket){
        if(listen_socket){
            std::cout<< "Listening on port" << 8766<< std::endl;
        };
    })
    .ws<SocketData>("/*",uWS::TemplatedApp<false>::WebSocketBehavior<SocketData> {//I have to explicitly declare the type of this struct.
    .open = [](auto *ws){
        std::cout<< "test"<< std::endl;
    },
    .message = [](auto *ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode){
    
        //The docs show how to send messages from this context, but no other method is demonstrated.
        ws->send("My message");// This works fine enough. 

        //What I'm trying to do.
        outerFunction(ws);
    }

    }).run();
}

void outerFunction(uWS::WebSocket<SSL, true, int> *ws){// I have NO idea what type would play nice in this spot. I've tried uWS::Websocket<false>, and others to no avail.
    //Processes information before replying
    ...
    //sends n amount of reply's.
    ws->send("sick Data.");//the outcome I'm looking for. 
}

int main()
{
    RelaySocket();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the `uWS::Websocket` is from `WebSocket.h`:

```
template <bool SSL, bool isServer, typename USERDATA>
struct WebSocket : AsyncSocket<SSL> {
    template <bool> friend struct TemplatedApp;
    template <bool> friend struct HttpResponse;
private:
    typedef AsyncSocket<SSL> Super;

    void *init(bool perMessageDeflate, CompressOptions compressOptions, BackPressure &&backpressure) {
        new (us_socket_ext(SSL, (us_socket_t *) this)) WebSocketData(perMessageDeflate, compressOptions, std::move(backpressure));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to update my question so it makes more sense. I was misunderstanding the linter errors I was getting.

I didn't realize what <args> the websocket type was expecting. I did read/import the websocket.h, but that doesn't help much if I'm bad at c++.

your comment helped clarify that for me.